# How to convert a string in format "property:value,property2:value" to xml in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, type-conversion

I need to convert the following text to XML

```
{"name":"daniel & sophia","age":20,"year":2009,"weight":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"dani,da"}{"name":"charls & lina","age":22,"year":2007,"weight":19.0"points":3,"alias":"carlos,lini"}
```

to

```
<participants>
    <participant>
        <name>daniel & sophia</name>
        <age>20</age>
        <year>2009</year>
        <weight>15.1</weight>
        <points>3</points>
        <alias>dani,da</alias>
    </participant>
    <participant>
        <name>charls & lina</name>
        <age>22</age>
        <year>2007</year>
        <weight>19.0</weight>
        <points>3</points>
        <alias>carlos,lini</alias>
    </participant>
<participants>
```

I tried to insert the data to a temporary table and then replace "{}" characteres. Then I tried to convert with XML function but I really don't know how to replicate the name of each item.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Campo VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
(
    Campo
)
VALUES
(
'{"name":"daniel & sophia","age":20,"year":2009,"weight":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"dani,da"}{"name":"charls & lina","age":22,"year":2007,"weight":19.0"points":3,"alias":"carlos,lini"}'
)

SELECT 
        CONVERT
        (
            XML, '<participants>' + 
            REPLACE
            (
                REPLACE
                (
                    REPLACE
                    (
                        REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT Campo AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')), '{', '<participant>'),'}','</participant>') + '</participants>'
                        ,'<participant>"'
                        ,'<participant><dato>'
                    )
                    , '","'
                    , '</dato><dato>'
                )
                , '</participant>'
                , '</dato></participant>'
            )
        ) 

            AS xmlname
    FROM #tmp
```

And this is what I get, but It is wrong:

```
<participants>
  <participant>
    <dato>name":"daniel &amp; sophia</dato>
    <dato>age":20,"year":2009,"weigth":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"dani,da"</dato>
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <dato>name":"charls &amp; lina</dato>
    <dato>age":22,"year":2007,"weigth":19.0,"points":3,"alias":"carlos,lini"</dato>
  </participant>
</participants>
```

> **NOTE**: The amount of The number of nodes within the Participant node is
>   unknown, it can be more than 100 and I would really like it to be a
>   dynamic query. (Without using EXEC "sql code")

Comment: Do you wish for our code to correct the spelling of `weight` also?

Comment: Shouldn't the second group of fields in your desired `XML` be based on `charls & lina`?

Comment: What is your SQL Server's version? There is [native JSON support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server) starting with SS2016, but your string is not absolutely valid JSON...

Comment: @toonice I'm sorry. I will correct this. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Shungo I use SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Cappelletti's answer is great, as long, as you know the column names in advance. The following approach will help you in cases, where you have to deal with such structures dynamically.

It is ugly, to create XML on string level (as I do it in the final `SELECT` like `SELECT '<' + innerNvp.Name + '>' +`, but it is a working possibility to deal with column names dynamically. Otherwise you'd either have to know all columns in advance, or you'd need to go the path of *dynamic SQL* with `EXEC`. There's one thing to keep in mind: The names in your structure (like `"name"` must be valid XML-tag-names.

**one general hint**: All approaches here try to cut your parts on string level. This might break, if there is a `}` or a `,"` or a `:` in an unexpected place...

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)='{"name":"daniel & sophia","age":20,"year":2009,"weigth":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"dani,da"}{"name":"charls & lina","age":22,"year":2009,"weigth":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"carlos,lini"}';

WITH SplittedAtClosingCurly AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @str AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'}','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS TheRows
)
,SplittedAtCommaQuote AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNr
           ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT Rw.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',"','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)  AS TheRow
    FROM SplittedAtClosingCurly
    CROSS APPLY TheRows.nodes(N'/x[text()]') AS A(Rw)
)
,SplittedAtDoubleDot AS
(
    SELECT  RowNr
           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS TplNr
           ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT Tpl.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),':','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)  AS TheTupel
    FROM SplittedAtCommaQuote
    CROSS APPLY TheRow.nodes(N'/x[text()]') AS A(Tpl) 
)
,DerivedTable_NameValuePairs AS
(
    SELECT RowNr
          ,TplNr
          ,REPLACE(REPLACE(TheTupel.value(N'/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'{',''),'"','') AS Name
          ,REPLACE(REPLACE(TheTupel.value(N'/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'{',''),'"','') AS Value
    FROM SplittedAtDoubleDot
)

SELECT CAST(
           (
            SELECT '<' + innerNvp.Name + '>' + (SELECT innerNvp.Value AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')) + '</' + innerNvp.Name + '>'
            FROM DerivedTable_NameValuePairs AS innerNvp
            WHERE innerNvp.RowNr=nvp.RowNr
            ORDER BY TplNr
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
           ).value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS XML)
FROM DerivedTable_NameValuePairs AS nvp
GROUP BY RowNr
FOR XML PATH('participant'),ROOT('participants')
```

Comment: Digging the dynamic approach  +1

Comment: @Shnugo, This code returns exactly I need! In additional help, can you teach me how I can use this code with CROSS APPLY at the end of CTE? I need to convert this final xml to a sql table.

Comment: @JotaPardo sorry, I don't get this. What is your final Goal?

Comment: @Shnugo, I want to convert this xml to a sql table. I use CROSS APPLY at the end of yout CTE but I cuoldn't

Comment: @JotaPardo Do you need further assistance? If you replace my last select with `SELECT * FROM DerivedTable_NameValuePairs` you'd get a *sql table* directly. This is a *name-value-pair* table, you can bind as `1:n` to a row's table. With dynamically defined structures this **can** be a good way... Btw: **There is no way to create a physical table with dynamically named columns without dynamic SQL.** What you have to think about: How do you want to deal with this later? It is hard to query against a table, where you do not know the structure and names in advance.

Answer (score 2):

** -- Updated for Updated Question --**

With the help of a Parse/Split UDF.  Just about any Parse/Split UDF would do the trick.  I did however supply mine.

This approach can be applied to any portion of your core data.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Campo varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'{"name":"daniel & sophia","age":20,"year":2009,"weight":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"dani,da"}{"name":"charls & lina","age":22,"year":2007,"weight":19.0"points":3,"alias":"carlos,lini"}')

Select [name]   = max(case when Item='name'   then Value end)
      ,[age]    = max(case when Item='age'    then Value end)
      ,[year]   = max(case when Item='year'   then Value end)
      ,[weight] = max(case when Item='weight' then Value end)
      ,[points] = max(case when Item='points' then Value end)
      ,[alias]  = max(case when Item='alias'  then Value end)
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,RowNr = B.RetSeq
              ,Item  = replace(replace(left(C.RetVal,charindex(':',C.RetVal)-1),'"',''),'{','')
              ,Value = replace(replace(right(C.RetVal,len(C.RetVal)-charindex(':',C.RetVal)),'"',''),'}','')
         From @YourTable A
         Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Campo,'}{') B    -- NOTE: Should really be },{
         Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](B.RetVal,',"') C
        -- YOUR WHERE STATEMENT HERE
      ) A
 Group By ID,RowNr
 Order By ID,RowNr
 For XML Path('participant'),Root('participants'),Type
```

**Returns**

```
<participants>
  <participant>
    <name>daniel &amp; sophia</name>
    <age>20</age>
    <year>2009</year>
    <weight>15.1</weight>
    <points>3</points>
    <alias>dani,da</alias>
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <name>charls &amp; lina</name>
    <age>22</age>
    <year>2007</year>
    <weight>19.0points:3</weight>
    <alias>carlos,lini</alias>
  </participant>
</participants>
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```

**One final note:**

If you can't use or want an UDF, this can easily be converted to in-line.

> **EDIT - In-line Approach**

```
Select [name]   = max(case when Item='name'   then Value end)
      ,[age]    = max(case when Item='age'    then Value end)
      ,[year]   = max(case when Item='year'   then Value end)
      ,[weight] = max(case when Item='weight' then Value end)
      ,[points] = max(case when Item='points' then Value end)
      ,[alias]  = max(case when Item='alias'  then Value end)
 From (
        Select A.ID
              ,RowNr = B.RetSeq
              ,Item  = replace(replace(left(C.RetVal,charindex(':',C.RetVal)-1),'"',''),'{','')
              ,Value = replace(replace(right(C.RetVal,len(C.RetVal)-charindex(':',C.RetVal)),'"',''),'}','')
         From YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Campo,'}{','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                     ) B
         Cross Apply (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(B.RetVal,',"','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                     ) C
        -- Your WHERE STATEMENT here --
      ) A
 Group By ID,RowNr
 Order By ID,RowNr
 For XML Path('participant'),Root('participants'),Type
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: Hi John, I have correctly corrected the weight of the word (Sorry for my English). I have corrected the repeated node points for the correct one which is Alias. I removed the quotes from the Alias node that should not be (I was wrong, sorry). And on the other hand it is not a JSON file. In fact it is a text file that is generated when performing a backup of a software and I must convert it to a SQL table.

Comment: In the order of your ideas, I tried and studied the code you sent and (you updated it before I finished answering) ... I would like to try the option without using UDF, which is surely what I require. And the issue is that I do not know how many items the Participant node can have. Here I put 6 example nodes, but it really is more than 90 and writing the query with all SELECT aliases would take me a long time. (I already added this clarification to my question).

Comment: @JotaPardo Don't apologize for your English, my Spanish is laughable :).  I saw your updates and modified my answer.  I just assumed it was JSON because it was soooo close

Comment: @JotaPardo Considering you have a dynamic number of nodes Shnugo's answer may be best, but I will add the in-line version, but that means you whout have to add 90 fields in the top query.... which is not elegant

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I understand!

Comment: @JotaPardo Just to be complete, I added the in-line approach

Answer (score 2):

This query returns an equivalent attribute-type xml like this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
         DROP TABLE #tmp

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
   Id INT IDENTITY,
   Campo VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
(
   Campo
)
VALUES
(
'{"name":"daniel & sophia","age":20,"year":2009,"weigth":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"dani,da"}{"name":"charls & lina","age":22,"year":2009,"weigth":15.1,"points":3,"alias":"carlos,lini"}'
)

SELECT  (select (CAST(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
                        replace(replace(Replace(t.Campo, '{"', '<participant '), '"}','" />'), '":"', '":'),'","',',"')
                        , '":', '":"'),',"','","'), '":"', '="'), '","', '" '), '&',',')   AS XML) 
                )
           FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('participants')) as xml
FROM #tmp t
```

`&` is illegal in xml, then i replaced it with `,`.

Result:

```
<participants>
    <participant name="daniel , sophia" age="20" year="2009" weigth="15.1" points="3" alias="dani,da"/>
    <participant name="charls , lina" age="22" year="2009" weigth="15.1" points="3" alias="carlos,lini"/>
</participants>
```

Comment: I like the idea to transform this into attribute centered XML. You might replace the `&` with `&amp;`

Comment: It is a great idea. I understood the pont of <participant property="value" property="value" ... /> but I need transform the data to the format I described.

Comment: Hi TriV, I just added one more answer with a `FLWOR XQuery` which would transform your result to an element centered one (Admittably not the needed shape...). Might be interesting for you...

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo.

Answer (score 2):

I add this as a new answer, it is an addition to TriV's answer actually:

The transformation to attribute centered XML is a good idea. You might go one step further with a `FLWOR XQuery` approach:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<participants>
    <participant name="daniel &amp; sophia" age="20" year="2009" weigth="15.1" points="3" alias="dani,da"/>
    <participant name="charls &amp; lina" age="22" year="2009" weigth="15.1" points="3" alias="carlos,lini"/>
</participants>';

SELECT @xml.query
('
    <participants>
    {
        for $p in /participants/participant
        return
        <participant>
        {
            for $attr in $p/@*
            return <data name="{local-name($attr)}" value="{string($attr)}"/>
        }
        </participant>
    }
    </participants>
');
```

The result

```
<participants>
  <participant>
    <data name="name" value="daniel &amp; sophia" />
    <data name="age" value="20" />
    <data name="year" value="2009" />
    <data name="weigth" value="15.1" />
    <data name="points" value="3" />
    <data name="alias" value="dani,da" />
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <data name="name" value="charls &amp; lina" />
    <data name="age" value="22" />
    <data name="year" value="2009" />
    <data name="weigth" value="15.1" />
    <data name="points" value="3" />
    <data name="alias" value="carlos,lini" />
  </participant>
</participants>
```

Regrettfully this approach does not support dynamically created elements.

### UPDATE: Slightly different, even closer:

The following query will place the values as element's `text()`, while the element's name is still an attribute...

```
SELECT @xml.query
('
    <participants>
    {
        for $p in /participants/participant
        return
        <participant>
        {
            for $attr in $p/@*
            return <data name="{local-name($attr)}">{string($attr)}</data>
        }
        </participant>
    }
    </participants>');
```

The result

```
<participants>
  <participant>
    <data name="name">daniel &amp; sophia</data>
    <data name="age">20</data>
    <data name="year">2009</data>
    <data name="weigth">15.1</data>
    <data name="points">3</data>
    <data name="alias">dani,da</data>
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <data name="name">charls &amp; lina</data>
    <data name="age">22</data>
    <data name="year">2009</data>
    <data name="weigth">15.1</data>
    <data name="points">3</data>
    <data name="alias">carlos,lini</data>
  </participant>
</participants>
```